# Rosalind: overlap graphs

Tags: python, string, graph-theory

I have come across a problem on Rosalind that I think I ave solved correctly, yet I get told my answer is incorrect. The problem can be found here: http://rosalind.info/problems/grph/

It's basic graph theory, more specifically it deals with returning an adjacency list of overlapping DNA strings.

"For a collection of strings and a positive integer k, the overlap graph for the strings is a directed graph Ok in which each string is represented by a node, and string s is connected to string t with a directed edge when there is a length k suffix of s that matches a length k prefix of t, as long as s≠t; we demand s≠t to prevent directed loops in the overlap graph (although directed cycles may be present).

Given: A collection of DNA strings in FASTA format having total length at most 10 kbp.

Return: The adjacency list corresponding to O3. You may return edges in any order."

So, if you've got:

> Rosalind_0498
>   AAATAAA
>
> Rosalind_2391
>   AAATTTT
>
> Rosalind_2323
>   TTTTCCC
>
> Rosalind_0442
>   AAATCCC
>
> Rosalind_5013
>   GGGTGGG

you must return:

Rosalind_0498 Rosalind_2391

Rosalind_0498 Rosalind_0442

Rosalind_2391 Rosalind_2323

My python code, after having parsed the FASTA file containing the DNA strings, is as follows:

```
        listTitle = []
        listContent = []

    #SPLIT is the parsed list of DNA strings

    #here i create two new lists, one (listTitle) containing the four numbers identifying a particular string, and the second (listContent) containing the actual strings ('>Rosalind_' has been removed, because it is what I split the file with)

        while i < len(SPLIT):
            curr = SPLIT[i]
            title = curr[0:4:1]
            listTitle.append(title)
            content = curr[4::1]
            listContent.append(content)
            i+=1

        start = []
        end = []

        #now I create two new lists, one containing the first three chars of the string and the second containing the last three chars, a particular string's index will be the same in both lists, as well as in the title list

        for item in listContent:
            start.append(item[0:3:1])
            end.append(item[len(item)-3:len(item):1])

        list = []

   #then I iterate through both lists, checking if the suffix and prefix are equal, but not originating from the same string, and append their titles to a last list

        p=0
        while p<len(end):
            iterator=0
            while iterator<len(start):
                if p!=iterator:
                    if end[p] == start[iterator]:
                        one=listTitle[p]
                        two=listTitle[iterator]
                        list.append(one)
                        list.append(two)
                iterator+=1
            p+=1

#finally I print the list in the format that they require for the answer

        listInc=0

        while listInc < len(list):
                print "Rosalind_"+list[listInc]+' '+"Rosalind_"+list[listInc+1]
                listInc+=2
```

Where am I going wrong? Sorry that the code is a bit tedious, I have had very little training in python

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure what is wrong with your code, but here is an approach that might be considered more "pythonic".

I'll suppose that you've read your data into a dictionary mapping names to DNA strings:

```
{'Rosalind_0442': 'AAATCCC',
 'Rosalind_0498': 'AAATAAA',
 'Rosalind_2323': 'TTTTCCC',
 'Rosalind_2391': 'AAATTTT',
 'Rosalind_5013': 'GGGTGGG'}
```

We define a simple function that checks whether a string `s1` has a `k`-suffix matching the `k`-prefix of a string `s2`:

```
def is_k_overlap(s1, s2, k):
    return s1[-k:] == s2[:k]
```

Then we look at all combinations of DNA sequences to find those that match. This is made easy by `itertools.combinations`:

```
import itertools
def k_edges(data, k):
    edges = []
    for u,v in itertools.combinations(data, 2):
        u_dna, v_dna = data[u], data[v]

        if is_k_overlap(u_dna, v_dna, k):
            edges.append((u,v))

        if is_k_overlap(v_dna, u_dna, k):
            edges.append((v,u))

    return edges
```

For example, on the data above we get:

```
>>> k_edges(data, 3)
[('Rosalind_2391', 'Rosalind_2323'),
 ('Rosalind_0498', 'Rosalind_2391'),
 ('Rosalind_0498', 'Rosalind_0442')]
```